# Matplotlib backend error in spyder console?

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda, backend, spyder

Any ideas what to do about the following error in my spyder (5.0.0) console?

```
Output from spyder call 'show_mpl_backend_errors':

=========================================================================
NOTE: The following error appeared when setting your Matplotlib backend!!
=========================================================================

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hana\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\console\kernel.py", line 735, in _set_mpl_backend
    get_ipython().run_line_magic(magic, backend)
  File "C:\Users\hana\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2326, in run_line_magic
    result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-109>", line 2, in matplotlib
  File "C:\Users\hana\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\IPython\core\magic.py", line 187, in <lambda>
    call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
  File "C:\Users\hana\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\IPython\core\magics\pylab.py", line 99, in matplotlib
    gui, backend = self.shell.enable_matplotlib(args.gui.lower() if isinstance(args.gui, str) else args.gui)
  File "C:\Users\hana\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3431, in enable_matplotlib
    pt.activate_matplotlib(backend)
  File "C:\Users\hana\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.py", line 320, in activate_matplotlib
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Users\hana\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 36, in <module>
    import matplotlib.colorbar
  File "C:\Users\hana\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py", line 44, in <module>
    import matplotlib.contour as contour
  File "C:\Users\hana\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\contour.py", line 17, in <module>
    import matplotlib.text as text
  File "C:\Users\hana\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .textpath import TextPath  # Unused, but imported by others.
  File "C:\Users\hana\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\textpath.py", line 11, in <module>
    from matplotlib.mathtext import MathTextParser
  File "C:\Users\hana\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mathtext.py", line 27, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File "C:\Users\hana\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 94, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (C:\Users\hana\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\PIL\__init__.py)
```

I currently have matplotlib 3.3.4, tried changing the setting from inline to automatic and reinstalling anaconda but the error is still there :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled anaconda again, then deleted all leftovers from the system directories (%appdata% & %programfiles%) and from Windows Registry.

After installing it again the error disappeared. :)

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) I'm glad you were able to solve this problem by yourself. For next time, please avoid installing packages with `pip` and remove this directory `C:\Users\hana\AppData\Roaming\Python\` (you don't need to uninstall Anaconda).